# aiohttp не видит ClientSession

Tags: python, асинхронность, pip, aiohttp

При попытке запустить код, выдает ошибку:

```
AttributeError: module 'aiohttp' has no attribute 'ClientSession'
```

Участок кода:

```
async def main():
        url = 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240'
        tasks = []

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            for i in range(10):
                task = asyncio.create_task(get_file(url, session))
                tasks.append(task)

            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Пробовал переустановить aiohttp, но результат один и тот же.

Comment: А как называется ваш файл, в котором вы код этот пишите?

Comment: и папка в которой лежит проект как называется, какие файлы лежат рядом? retorta намекает на конфликт имени модуля с именем файла в проекте.